# planning a virtualised environment

Tags: virtualization, moodle

I'm in the early stages of planning out a virtualised environment for our production system (Moodle). The layers are relatively simple:

web - Apache 2.2
Database - MySQL 5
PHP 5.2

My question is this, what is the generally accepted approach for distributing the above layers amongst phycsical servers? In this case, we are planning to have 2 physical servers. Should I aim to keep my web server cluster on a single physical server and database cluster on another? Or, replicate a full stack on both servers, in case one fails? Any insights into this would be a great help to me.

thanks,
Cathal.

Answer (score 0):

We use separate (virtual) servers, but do maintain separate stacks on each simply because the overheads are small and it allows for flexibility if we want to scale up/down. This is not for fallback however, because if one server is so broken that it's not web accessible, you probably won't be able to get data off it and onto the second server in order for it to be a useful replacement. Use proper backups for fallback and practice restoring from them regularly.

Moodle generally blocks on the PHP side rather than the DB side and we see roughly 3.5:1 PHP:MySQL CPU loads when they are on separate machines. With that in mind, you need to consider what the maximum capacity of one server is: you will get best performance if you have no network overhead between the machines at all, so bigger is better. If you can't do it with one, then making 2 VMS, one larger for PHP and one smaller for MySQL is the best option, but do benchmark the differences under load for your particular setup (use Apache [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) for this).

Our largest installs involve 70,000 users or so and we have two 4-CPU/8GB VMs, one for PHP and one for MySQL (although the DB one rarely goes above 30% CPU). This allows for about 400 concurrent connections via Apache. However, we are using a large farm of VMs and can scale up and down between 2 and 16 CPUs easily, so you may wish to consider one monster machine if you want flexibility.

For more information on Moodle performance, look [here](http://docs.moodle.org/22/en/Performance_recommendations), particularly under 'scalability'.